# SolrException URLDecoder: Invalid character encoding detected after position 79 of query string / form data (while parsing as UTF-8)

Tags: solarium, cakephp-2.6, solr5

HOW I can indexing from solarium rich data(msword and pdf files) from a dirctory who contient many files,
MY config is

```
$config = array(
         "endpoint" => array("localhost" => array("host"=>"127.0.0.1",
         "port"=>"8983", "path"=>"/solr", "core"=>"demo",)
        ) );
```

I try this code:

```
$dir = new Folder($dossier);
$files = $dir->find('.*\.*');
foreach ($files as $file) {
$file = new File($dir->pwd() . DS . $file);

$update = $client->createUpdate();

$query = $client->createExtract();
$query->setFile($file->pwd());
$query->setCommit(true);
$query->setOmitHeader(false);
$doc = $query->createDocument();
$doc->id =$file->pwd();
$doc->name = $file->name;
$doc->title = $file->name();
$query->setDocument($doc);

$result = $client->extract($query);
}
```

but after 10 second i have this error:

```
Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Operation timed out after 5039 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

and this ERROR in the trace og solr log :

```
 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: URLDecoder: Invalid character encoding detected after position 79 of query string / form data (while parsing as UTF-8)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.decodeChars(SolrRequestParsers.java:388)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.decodeBuffer(SolrRequestParsers.java:405)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parseFormDataContent(SolrRequestParsers.java:373)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString(SolrRequestParsers.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.parseQueryString(SolrRequestParsers.java:243)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.<init>(HttpSolrCall.java:172)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.getHttpSolrCall(SolrDispatchFilter.java:236)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a connect timeout: are you sure Solr is running and you're pointers are right?

On top of that,

- if it is a Solr problem, you should see the exact cause in the log
- if there's nothing in Solr log, then Solr (most probably) has nothing to do with that (i.e. your app never connected with Solr)

Comment: in this 10 seconds od time out solr index 64 files before this Error.

Comment: So you should have some trace in the Solr log

Comment: I fix it by send the right encoding of my data msword and pdf using headers:
$headers = array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data');